# AlamoFire + Google Analytics on same VC error after using GAIDictionaryBuilder

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods, swift2, alamofire

After using:

```
let gaBuilder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
```

Anywhere on a view controller, I get this error where I use Alamofire:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type "NSHTTPURLResponse?"
```

AF statement:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, loginUrl, parameters: loginParameters, encoding: .URL, headers: nil).response(queue: dispatch_get_main_queue(), completionHandler: { (request, response, data, errorType) -> Void in
```

It doesn't matter what I'm doing with GAIDictionaryBuilder (sending an event, setting parameters or using createScreenView) whenever I use it I get that error.

Here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is similar, the error "Cannot call value of non-function type "NSHTTPURLResponse?" occurs when I send the casted object like below:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

I think this is problem of XCode. For a work around, I implement an helpers function to cast object, then then the errors gone. The helpers like below:

```
class Helpers{

    class func ConvertGAIDictionaryBuilder(input: GAIDictionaryBuilder) -> [NSObject: AnyObject]{
        return input.build() as [NSObject: AnyObject]
    }
}
```

Then apply:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(Helpers.ConvertGAIDictionaryBuilder(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()))
```